# How to filter LocalDate from Map by only year?

Tags: java

I have this piece of code. I want to filter LocalDate variable using only Year nothing more. I have to filter people who has year of birth more than 1999

I add people to my list for example:

```
thePeopleList .add(new showPeople(340, "MR xyz", LocalDate.of(1991, 4, 28)));
thePeopleList .add(new showPeople(546, "MR bng", LocalDate.of(2020, 11, 30)));
```

This filter doesn't work. I am looking for a solution.

```
Map<Integer, People> thePeopleList = thePeople.getPeopleList().stream()
                .filter(people -> people.getBirthDate() > (2000))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(PeopleUsers::getIdNumber, people -> people));

    thePeopleList .entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Do you mean `showPeople.getBirthDate().getYear() > 1999`?

Comment: @Sweeper It can't be:   .filter(showPeople -> showPeople.getBirthDate().getYear() >= 2000)
It displays errors because Required type is: Map <Integer, People>
Provided: Map <Integer, Object>

Comment: What is `PeopleUsers` ? `thePeople.getPeopleList()` is a `List<People>` then why your using `PeopleUsers` in collecting map ? and why you add `someone` type in `thePeopleList ` ?

Comment: PeopleUsers is it a class where is for example private LocalDate birthDate;
I have uptated my post.

Comment: thePeople.getPeopleList() is List<PeopleUsers> ? please  add minimum reproducible code to undestand your problem

Comment: This dooesn't work .filter(showPeople -> showPeople.getBirthDate().getYear() > 1999)

Comment: It is:
public List<People> getPeopleList() {
        return new ArrayList<>(thePeopleList);
    }

Comment: And what is the type of `thePeopleList` ?

Comment: The type is PeopleUsers. This is a class where is for example private LocalDate birthDate; 

List<PeopleUsers> thePeopleList = new ArrayList<>();
I have uptated my post.

Comment: You are doing List<People> to List<PeopleUsers> which makes problem. Why don't you post your full code

Comment: My code is split into few files. Why it is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare Localdate with `(2000-1-1)`

You can use `.getYear()` function to get year from `Localdate` and compare in filter.

```
Map<Integer, People> thePeopleList = 
                 thePeople.getPeopleList().stream()
                .filter(showPeople -> showPeople.getBirthDate().getYear() > 1999)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(People::getIdNumber, showPeople -> showPeople));
```

Comment: It can't be:   .filter(showPeople -> showPeople.getBirthDate().getYear() >= 2000)
It displays errors because Required type is: Map <Integer, People>
Provided: Map <Integer, Object>

Comment: You are using list of `someone` after filter do any terminal operation like Collect in List. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

[`LocalDate#getYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getYear--) and [`Collectors#toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) are your friends:

```java
Map<Integer, People> thePeopleList = thePeople.getPeopleList().stream()
                .filter(showPeople -> showPeople.getBirthDate().getYear() >= 2000)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(People::getId, Function.identity()));
```

I would also suggest renaming the class `People` to `Person`. In Java instances of classes represent single objects.

Comment: It can't be:   .filter(showPeople -> showPeople.getBirthDate().getYear() >= 2000)
It displays errors because Required type is: Map <Integer, People>
Provided: Map <Integer, Object>

Comment: What's the return type of `thePeople.getPeopleList()`? `List<People>` or a raw `List`? The former is safer and will work.